# why I can't post from local angular app to RestHeart local test api runing on docker?

Tags: angular, docker, post, cors, restheart

I'm new to angular and got this situation in one of my classes:

I have a simple Angular app running on my localhost:4200, from witch i want to make a post to a RESTHEART local API.

As i got from the RESTHEART tutorial https://restheart.org/learn/tutorial/ I installed Docker and downloaded the docker-compose.yml and When running it, I find it in localhost:8080(I believe this part is ok)

I tried some info on the CORS but I didn find out how to enable it i n the RESTHEART api. I got some info on the RESTHEART that says it has CORS support but it was not a very clarifying text.

I have no problems when I try to post to https://beta.mrest.io/demo/messages , witch is not localhost

also, I followed the instructions in this page to get the api https://restheart.org/learn/setup/ with the exception of uncommenting the line "- ./etc:/opt/restheart/etc:ro", because it generated a error about invalid ports
(if you guys think is necessary I'll add the error later)

This is my ComponentService, from where I shoot the post request(I can't format it here to show the code in a decent way, i'm sory for that)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const host = 'http://localhost:8080/db/coll';
// const host = 'https://beta.mrest.io/demo/messages';

@Injectable()
export class ContatoComponentService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    enviarContato(contatoForm: any): Observable<Response> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('key', 'demo');
        const nomeCompleto = contatoForm.nomeCompleto;
        const email = contatoForm.contato.email;
        const mensagem = 'Mensagem de teste'; //             contatoForm.mensagem;
        console.log('nomeCompleto', nomeCompleto);
        console.log('email', email);
        console.log('mensagem', mensagem);

        return this.http.post(host, {email: email, from: nomeCompleto, message: mensagem}, { headers: headers});
    }
}
```

But when I do the post request to the api I get this error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/db/coll' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior due to security concerns, you can learn about it and possible work arounds over the following link https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

Answer (score 1):

By default RESTHeart always sends CORS headers. If you just start it with `docker-compose up` and then send an http `OPTIONS` request, you should verify that it responds correctly.

For example, below I first created a database "db" and a collection "coll" and then I'm using the [httpie](https://httpie.org) client (but you can use curl or any API UI):

```
http -a 'admin:changeit' OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/db/coll

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Length, Content-Type, Host, If-Match, Origin, X-Requested-With, User-Agent, No-Auth-Challenge
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, ETag, Auth-Token, Auth-Token-Valid-Until, Auth-Token-Location, X-Powered-By
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 14:39:18 GMT
X-Powered-By: restheart.org
```

Do you see exactly the same headers?

Your error message is "Request header field key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response": could you check your Javascript console in the browser and see if it receives any error after sending an `OPTIONS` request?

Moreover, remember that when POSTing the request must contain an Accept header for application/json

```
Accept: application/json
```

For example, below is the full request httpie is sending to RESTHeart while posting a simple JSON object to the "coll" collection:

```
http -v -a 'admin:changeit' POST http://localhost:8080/db/coll name='RESTHeart'

POST /db/coll HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Y2hhbmdlaXQ=
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9

{
    "name": "RESTHeart"
}
```

You can also tail RESTHeart's logs with:

```
docker logs -f restheart
```

Comment: with httpie i have no problem, only when I try to post to it from my application

Answer (score 1):

With RESTHeart you don't need the `key` header, which is not allowed by the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. So remove the following line code:

```
headers.append('key', 'demo');
```

`key` is only required with [mrest.io](https://mrest.io). On RESHeart web site you have some examples with the following note:

> Please note that the examples use the mrest.io cloud service for RESTHeart. It requires the api key and has a slightly different representation format.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the reply, when I remove that line I get 401(Unauthorized). Am I missing any config anywhere?

Comment: Unauthorized because you have authentication enabled so you need to pass the basic authentication header. Check on the docs https://restheart.org/learn/clients-authentication/ with Angular I suggest you to write and interceptor to add the Authorization header to all requests https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor